# How to add transition effect for BottomTabNavigator in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native

I am trying here something, but it is not working:

```js
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="TabOne"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="TabOne"
        component={TabOneNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="ios-code" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="TabTwo"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="ios-code" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

function TabBarIcon(props: { name: string; color: string }) {
  return <Ionicons size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
}

const TabOneStack = createStackNavigator<TabOneParamList>();

function TabOneNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="TabOneScreen"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Tab One Title', ...TransitionPresets.ScaleFromCenterAndroid }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const TabTwoStack = createStackNavigator<TabTwoParamList>();

function TabTwoNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabTwoStack.Navigator>
      <TabTwoStack.Screen
        name="TabTwoScreen"
        component={TabTwoScreen}
        options={{ 
          headerTitle: 'Tab Two Title',
          ...TransitionPresets.ScaleFromCenterAndroid
        }}
      />
    </TabTwoStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I guess it only work for stacked screens in stacked navigator side by side? Or am I doing something wrong? I did not find any useful information about this so I don't know how to pressed.

. Thank you!